# Polling database for updates from C# application

Tags: c#, jet, polling

I'm attempting to create my first "real" C# application - a small pet project to help schedule peer reviews at work.

Due to the insane amount of process/bureaucracy involved in implementing anything new - as well as the fact that I'm doing this away from managements eyes, on my own time, for the time being - I'm going to be writing this with an <s>MS Access</s> MS Jet Engine backend (i.e. an access mdb file) due to restrictions on how I can deploy this application to my co-workers.

My question is: how do I poll the database intermittently to grab updates (new requested reviews, messages from other developers requesting info, etc.) from the database?

Should I just drop a Timer on each form that needs the info and refresh everything when an update has occurred?

**Edit:**
I'm looking for advice specifically on how to implement the timer. I can't install things on workstations, I don't have access to servers (outside of storage space), and I can't host this myself due to the company's security requirements since our client has ridiculous DoD restrictions.

I guess I've figured this out anyway, since the "timer on form" solution works just fine (I don't know what I was thinking when I said I wanted a secondary solution for a CLI version as it clearly isn't needed.. it's very late).

Thanks!

Comment: you would be better off using SQL Server EXpress rather than MS access: http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/

Comment: @Mitch: Not an option since this needs to just sit out on a network drive. I work for a consulting company - a large, bureaucratic one - and I'd never be able to install something like SQL Server. I'm doing this with Access so I can get around this limitation.

Comment: I know it's not an ideal situation, but that's a large reason why I'm writing this - so I can gain some real experience with C# and get myself in a good position to get out of this company and find a decent job.

Comment: use MVC. u can install it (and sql) on a workstation (forget the server). 
learn mvc (and get a better job)!!

Comment: @cottsak: Given my other complaints about my employer, what makes you think I have the *ability* to install on my workstation? I'm worried enough about whether or not the runtime is installed, and if I can prove my app well enough to get that installed if it's not (likely "No.").

Comment: well if you want to use c# you will at least have Visual Studio installed. forget the test servers (on your pc or otherwise). use the development server that comes with VS!

Comment: I'm using Visual C# 2008 Express on my home machine. Surely you don't mean to tell me that VS is required on every machine I deploy to! ;-)

Comment: no of course not. i just thought you would have VS on the work pc - where you could develop it at work/home and then demo the POC on your work pc.

Comment: I intended to demo this with the executable on the share, along with a dummy copy of the database.

Comment: i really am trying to help you man. if you dont like my idea let me know and i'll lay off... but i really think this will do you so much better than the access approach.

you could easily set up a demo server on your home pc and serve it to the net. u got net at work right?

Comment: He is not using Access -- he's using Jet.

Comment: @David W. Fenton : the question says Access.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: if you want answers to a particular question, perhaps you should ask THAT question and not some other loosely related question.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I thought I was clear on the question: How do I implement the database polling? The rest of the question was intended to show why this needed to happen in the app, with no help from the database. Sorry for the incorrect terminology (Access/Jet), I didn't know it'd be such an issue.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: We're all Access-haters it seems. Sorry about your work environment. Been there, done that, got the t-shirt. Nice to know your enthusiasm for writing tools hasn't been completely quashed by the bureaucracy.

Comment: Only a moron would hate Access/Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start a background worker thread to do the refreshes in an infinite loop, and sleep at the end (or beginning) of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

develop your application as a aspnet MVC app. this way it's a web site and developers can simply refresh pages to get the latest results. this will help you in many ways: no polling, no access, web interface (very handy), [too many to mention]

start here - http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-395.aspx

**EDIT: more links:**

(these are great vids)

 * http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-396.aspx

 * http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-360.aspx

 * http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-361.aspx

Comment: this is -very- easy to learn. save yourself headaches with access and move to mvc, .net and sql server

Comment: I have the same issue with this as I do with the SQL Server Express idea (i.e. official channels, etc. when I just want a nice POC to show them it's doable.. trying to make things bearable at work..) in that I'll never get the company to host the site. I can't host it myself due to DoD restrictions.

Comment: d/l a free version of VMWare Workstation. there's heaps of options before you resort to Access.
what im really saying is - dont use access!! please! i beg you. i've been an access dev for years. you need to move on. now is always the best time.

Comment: He's not using Access -- he's using Jet as his data store.

Comment: Distinctions between Access and Jet are often lost on most people who aren't exerts in the field (and even to some who are). Didn't you think the NZ() function (actually part of the Access object model) was part of Jet last week? And you mistook Jet Blue (ESE) for Jet Red (.mdb), didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

orrite.. i'll crumble.

my best suggestion to poll the access data store would be to use a System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder where the mdb file lives. this way you can craft your code to poll at an interval but only when the Changed event fires. this should chew less cpu and disk access.

hope this helps. :D

Comment: @cottsak: Thanks for the tip. One question though (just to add more fuel to this fire): Wouldn't this implementation mean that whenever the database is updated, all instances of the application would hammer the database at once? I think if all relevant teams ran this, there'd be around 30 instances.

Comment: (cont..)  and I thought that Access (not necessarily jet, I suppose) is/used to be theoretically limited to 255 users, with a practical limit of around 30ish. I could be talking out of my ass though.

Comment: the practical limit u speak of is pretty accurate.

yeh i think you're right - the clients will hammer the db when there is a change to the disk. but u'll get that with any polling. only with my suggestion it will happen less frequently, but at synchronized points in time. up to you hey.